# jenkins question - Adding post section to script based & difference between methods

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 2 questions regarding jenkins

**1. What is the difference between the 2 methods?**

Method 1

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { 
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
```

Method 2

```
node ("jenkins-nodes") {
    stage("git clone"){
        echo 'Hello World'    }
    }
```

2. As I understand in the first method I can add **Post** section that will be running regardless of the result of the job.  I wish to add the same post section for the second method, but it is not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: First method is written in **Declarative** pipeline syntax and the second one is written in **Scripted** pipeline syntax. You can read more about the differences at [Pipeline Syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

Comment: @NoamHelmer Recommend to expand into answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between the 2 methods?

As [Noam Helmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13110835/noam-helmer) wrote, `pipeline{}` is [declarative](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) syntax and and `node{}` is [scripted](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) syntax.

In general I recommend to always use `pipeline{}` as it makes common tasks easier to write and visualization using Blue Ocean plugin works best with declarative pipeline.

When declarative pipeline becomes too unflexible, you can insert scripted blocks using the `script{}` step in a declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { 
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Hello World'               
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A cleaner approach is to define a function, which is scripted by definition and use that as a custom step in declarative pipeline. Note this works even without `script{}`!

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { 
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                myStep 42
            }
        }
    }
}

void myStep( def x ) {
    echo "Hello World $x"        // prints "Hello World 42"
}
```

In complex pipelines that use lots of custom code, I usually have one function per stage. This keeps the `pipeline{}` clean and makes it easy to see the overall structure of the pipeline, without `script{}` clutter all over the place.

> As I understand in the first method I can add Post section that will
> be running regardless of the result of the job. I wish to add the same
> post section for the second method, but it is not working. Any ideas?

`post{}` is only available in declarative pipeline, but not within a scripted pipeline or a scripted section of a declarative pipeline. You can use `try{} catch{} finally{}` instead. `catch{}` runs only when an error occurs, `finally{}` always runs. You can use both or either of `catch{}` and `finally{}`.

```
node ("jenkins-nodes") {
    stage("git clone"){
        echo 'Hello World'    
        try {
            // some steps that may fail
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            echo "An error happened: $e"
            // Rethrow exception, to let the build fail.
            // If you remove "throw", the error would be ignored by Jenkins.
            throw  
        }
        finally {
            echo "Cleaning up some stuff"
        }
    }
}
```